# How to specify which thread(s) room live queries to run on?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a class in my app with executors for disk/network operations, like [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/AppExecutors.kt). Is it possible to tell Room to use one of those to execute live queries?

Comment: Can I decide a coroutine context for live queries? Does room even support coroutines?

Comment: Does it makes sense to wrap a dao operation that returns LiveData in a coroutine?   The query is still going to be executed in a thread decided by room.

Comment: you are right. They run already asynchronously

Answer (score 4):

If you use LiveData then you do not need to use an `Executor` in order to select data. Because LiveData, by default, runs off the UI thread.

You would need it though for inserts, updates and deletes.

And you could use it like this I think:

```
executor.diskIO().execute(...runnable...);    // recommended for db actions
executor.networkIO().execute(...runnable...); // not recommended for db  because a pool of 3 threads can run concurrently, could yield issues
```

This one on the other hand cannot be used for db queries because it runs on the UI thread (look at the private inner class). This would defeat the purpose of having db queries running off the UI thread. It is for specific use cases where you need to be in the UI thread.

```
executor. mainThread().execute(...runnable...);
```

So to sum up:

- when using LiveData no need for an executor when doing a select statement
- for insert, delete, update or non LiveData objects you would need to run the query off the UI thread
- in that specific case you *have* to use `executor.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {...});`